# Error: Channel ended, no reply will be forthcoming

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, rabbitmq

i'm trying to use wascally (npm) inside a meteor application and i've got it set up and running.  however, i'm trying to use the `request()` function and chain `then()` statements on to it to deal with a response.

i'm getting an error that i can't seem to figure out because i don't even see a message going into my queue.

i've set up rabbitmq via cloneamqp.com so i am pretty sure it's not the actual rabbitmq install that's messed up... it's something to do with me.

here is my stack trace

```
W20150925-00:14:05.787(-4)? (STDERR)            throw e;
W20150925-00:14:05.787(-4)? (STDERR)                  ^
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Channel ended, no reply will be forthcoming
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at rej (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:189:7)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Channel.C._rejectPending (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:195:42)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Channel.C.toClosed (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:159:8)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Channel.C.accept (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:405:10)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:62:33)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.go (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:465:48)
W20150925-00:14:05.789(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
W20150925-00:14:05.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
W20150925-00:14:05.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
W20150925-00:14:05.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
```

i'm using meteor 1.2.0.1, rabbitmq 3.5.4, and wascally 0.2.7 from npm

i don't even know where to start with this error.

Comment: you can't require npm modules if you want to be able to do that you can use `https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm` and do `var Github = Meteor.npmRequire('github');` or if it's a package you can do it without an extra package: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends

Answer (score 0):

---

ExchangeBind problem answered here: [Operation failed: ExchangeBind; 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'dead.letters-q.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789007/operation-failed-exchangebind-404-not-found-with-message-not-found-no-exc/32792121#32792121)

---

turns out i was trying to configure `wascally` twice.  now i'm getting a different error!

```
Error: Operation failed: ExchangeBind; 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'dead.letters-q.1' in vhost 'jzywgjfv'"
```

which is weird because `dead.letters-q.1` is the queue bound to the exchange, not an exchange itself.  not sure if it's a library problem or just a bad error message.