# Operation failed: ExchangeBind; 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'dead.letters-q.1'

Tags: node.js, meteor, rabbitmq

as referenced in a previous question, i'm trying to use the `wascally` npm package with meteor and it's throwing what seems to be a setup/config error about my exchanges

```
W20150925-14:22:34.692(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20150925-14:22:34.693(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/when/lib/fatal.js:12
W20150925-14:22:34.693(-4)? (STDERR)            throw e;
W20150925-14:22:34.693(-4)? (STDERR)                  ^
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Operation failed: ExchangeBind; 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'dead.letters-q.1' in vhost 'jzywgjfv'"
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at reply (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:126:17)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at Channel.C.accept (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:399:7)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:62:33)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.go (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/wacoosta/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/wascally/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:465:48)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
W20150925-14:22:34.694(-4)? (STDERR)     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
W20150925-14:22:34.695(-4)? (STDERR)     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
W20150925-14:22:34.695(-4)? (STDERR)     at TCP.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

here is my rabbit config:

```
{
    connection: {
      user: Meteor.settings.rabbitmq.username,
      pass: Meteor.settings.rabbitmq.password,
      server: Meteor.settings.rabbitmq.server,
      //port: 5672,
      //timeout: 2000
      vhost: Meteor.settings.rabbitmq.vhost
    },
    exchanges:[
      { name: messages.exchanges.dead, type: 'direct' },
      { name: messages.exchanges.tmdb, type: 'direct' },
      { name: messages.exchanges.graph, type: 'direct' }
    ],
    queues:[
      { name: messages.queues.tmdb.read, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.tmdb.dead, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.graph.read, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.graph.write, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead }
    ],
    bindings:[{
      exchange: messages.exchanges.tmdb,
      target: messages.queues.tmdb.read,
      keys: [
        messages.keys.tmdb.read.imdb,
        messages.keys.tmdb.read.movies,
        messages.keys.tmdb.read.tv,
        messages.keys.tmdb.read.credits,
        messages.keys.tmdb.read.people
      ]
    },{
      exchange: messages.exchanges.dead,
      target: messages.queues.dead,
      keys: [
        messages.keys.tmdb.dead,
        messages.keys.graph.dead
      ]
    },{
      exchange: messages.exchanges.graph,
      target: messages.queues.graph.read,
      keys: [
        messages.keys.graph.read.any,
        messages.keys.graph.read.movies,
        messages.keys.graph.read.tv,
        messages.keys.graph.read.people,
        messages.keys.graph.read.places
      ]
    },{
      exchange: messages.exchanges.graph,
      target: messages.queues.graph.write,
      keys: [
        messages.keys.graph.write.any,
        messages.keys.graph.write.movies,
        messages.keys.graph.write.tv,
        messages.keys.graph.write.people,
        messages.keys.graph.write.places,
        messages.keys.graph.write.relationships
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
```

i checked in my rabbitmq admin panel and i've explicitly set up a binding between my dead letters exchange and queue, so i'm not sure what it's talking about or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eureka! after some digging through the code and digging into the rabbitmq dashboard, i found the problem.

```
  exchanges:[
      { name: messages.exchanges.dead, type: 'direct' },
      { name: messages.exchanges.tmdb, type: 'direct' },
      { name: messages.exchanges.graph, type: 'direct' }
    ],
    queues:[
      { name: messages.queues.tmdb.read, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.tmdb.dead, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.graph.read, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
      { name: messages.queues.graph.write, subscribe: false, durable: true, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead }
    ]
```

i was defining the `messages.exchanges.dead` exchange, and setting that as the `deadLetter` exchange for my various queues.  the problem was that the `dead-letters.q1` queue was **NOT** being defined in the `queues:[]` array.

this meant that while the `dead-letters-ex.1` exchange existed and could have messages routed to it, there was no `dead-letters-q.1` created or available to route those messages to.

```
ExchangeBind; 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'dead.letters-q.1'
```

the `ExchangeBind` error was what got me looking at the bindings of queues to exchanges which led me down this rabbit hole to a solution (pun intended).

now my config looks like this:

```
exchanges:[
  { name: messages.exchanges.dead, type: 'direct' },
  { name: messages.exchanges.tmdb, type: 'direct' },
  { name: messages.exchanges.graph, type: 'direct' }
],
queues:[
  { name: messages.queues.dead, subscribe: false, durable: false },
  { name: messages.queues.tmdb.read, subscribe: false, durable: false, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
  { name: messages.queues.tmdb.dead, subscribe: false, durable: false, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
  { name: messages.queues.graph.read, subscribe: false, durable: false, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead },
  { name: messages.queues.graph.write, subscribe: false, durable: false, deadLetter: messages.exchanges.dead }
]
```

and i can continue building and debugging other parts of the application.

Comment: thank you for posting this! those things are really not debuggable. How do you show the `exchanges` and `queues` you show here?